# Excel: Looking date dependant (column A) for a specific word in column B and return value of column C. How to?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

In column A are dates sorted ascending. In the cells of column B is text. And in C are numbers.

What I try to achieve: I would like to have the value in C of the row where in B is text containing the string "xyz" and in A is a date of the year 2007. This should be done by a formula. I was trying to use vlookup but this doesn't incoperate the use of the date as a second criteria plus it only returns the first hit.

I have a sample excel file but apparently I cannot upload things here:/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can post a small sample (input as well as output) here as you cannot upload file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this formula where E1 = a date (to match column A) and F1 = a text (to match column B).

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A6=$E$1)*($B$2:$B$6=$F$1)*($C$2:$C$6))
```

When you expand the ranges to suit your needs - I would use named ranges for better transparency and easier management - make sure that all 3 ranges are of identical size.

Comment: Almost there...this formula compares the strings in B and F1 and produces a hit if they are identical but I would like to get a result if the string in F1 is just a part of the text in B, e.g. the String in F1 is 'test'. If there is a text in B like 'Testseries succesful' it would meet my criteria.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do that. I suggest you take this answer and ask another question how to modify it to accept partial criteria. In that way you will get more experts to look at it in a different light